I want to remove an app, but snap remove --purge <app> returns: "remove-snap "change in progress n WSL2
I tried other solutions found here and on google but they don't seem to work on WSL2.
The command snap changes returns:
ID   Status  Spawn                    Ready                    Summary
10   Done    yesterday at 16:23 CEST  yesterday at 16:23 CEST  Auto-refresh snap "core22"
11   Abort   today at 15:19 CEST      -                        Remove "prettier" snap

The command sudo snap abort 11 does not return anything but then snap changes returns
again
ID   Status  Spawn                    Ready                    Summary
10   Done    yesterday at 16:23 CEST  yesterday at 16:23 CEST  Auto-refresh snap "core22"
11   Abort   today at 15:19 CEST      -                        Remove "prettier" snap 

Hence, if I run sudo snap remove --purge prettier I get error: snap "prettier" has "remove-snap" change in progress.
